# VBA - Assigning Unique IDs to Sheet Rows Based on Several Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently trying to solve the following problem:

I have an Excel Spreadsheet containing names and birthdates from several people. I would like to assign a unique ID to every unique person in a new column. (Person A gets 1, Person B gets 2...)
Giving out an ID only based on birthdate would lead to people with the same date getting the same ID; same thing for names.

**A person can appear more than once on the list.**

So, I want to assign the ID based on both the name **AND** the birthdate to avoid confusion, and if person A appears 3 times for example, have the ID be the same every time.

Does anyone know how to solve this using VBA code?

I would very much appreciate any input. **:)**

Comment: welcome to SO, in order to help you, you need to try at least some lines of code first because site focus it's not to make solutions from scratch. Post a try and we'll gladly help.

Comment: This can also be done with a formula

Comment: Excel is not a relational database engine. What happens to the related records when a row is deleted with its ID? Use Access, or SQL Server. Doing this in Excel is doomed.

Comment: I have to do it on Excel because the data is located on an Excel sheet, but thanks for the tip, I will explore the opton :)

Comment: Start by copying the data and eliminating the duplicates in the copy ("person A appears 3 times" - make that 1), then assign each a unique numeric ID; go back to your with-dupes list, and lookup the ID based on whatever criteria you came up with (DoB+Name) to determine whether a "person" is actually unique.

Comment: `Id = Name & "_" & birthdate`

Comment: @TimWilliams that's actually the single best way to do this. If the ID absolutely must be a numeric value, then computing a hash of this concatenation would work too.